# Unable to access uploaded resources in Spring on Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I am making a web app in Spring boot. One of the features is where I upload an image and show it to the users on another page. To do this, I have added a resource handler with the file path.

Locally, it works quite well and shows all images. But on deploying to Heroku, the app could not resolve the file path and result in a 404 error. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong in this case.

Here's my MvC configuration:

```
package com.shubhanshu02.shop.Config;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;    
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        exposeDirectory("product-photos", registry);
    }

    private void exposeDirectory(String dirName, ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        Path uploadDir = Paths.get(dirName);
        String uploadPath = uploadDir.toFile().getAbsolutePath();

        if (dirName.startsWith("../")) {
            dirName.replace("../", "");
        }
        registry.addResourceHandler("/" + dirName + "/**").addResourceLocations("file://" + uploadPath + "/");
    }
}
```

For uploading the image, I am using this class:
package com.shubhanshu02.shop;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class FileUploadUtil {
    public static void saveFile(String uploadDir, String fileName, MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
        Path uploadPath = Paths.get(uploadDir);
        if (!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {
            Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
        }

        try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
            Path filePath = uploadPath.resolve(fileName);
            Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException("Could not save image file: " + fileName, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And to upload the image, I use this controller:

```
@PostMapping("/addproduct")
public String addProductPOSTHandler(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product,
        @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile multipartFile, Model model) throws IOException {

    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    product.setProductImage(fileName);
    if (productRepository.getProductbyName(product.getProductName()) != null) {
        return "redirect:addProduct?error";
    }

    productRepository.save(product);
    String uploadDir = "product-photos/";
    FileUploadUtil.saveFile(uploadDir, fileName, multipartFile);
    return "redirect:addProduct?success";
}
```

Comment: You can't store images on the local filesystem and expect them to stay there for any meaningful amount of time due to [Heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). I'm about to link a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thank you.